# meaning sentence present perfect continuous

Tags: difference, present-perfect-progressive

In a movie, someone says "she has been possessing people", when speaking about a "witch".

Does this sentence mean that "she" has possessed people for a while and continues to possess people?

What could be the difference with "she has possessed people" and the previous example?

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers, but like to add that the continuous is also used to express a habit, which has been going on for sometime.

Comment: Ok, the sentence with continuous talks either about a finished action right now or an action that is going on in the present and the sentence with present perfect simple just talks about a past action with connection with present : Here there is a connection because they do not know what will happen to them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've removed a comment about current relevance, could you please add that comment? It was really helpful.

Comment: It's not great English because witches don't possess people. People are possessed by [a demon or other thingie] and witches cast spells on people. In any case, it implies another tense with an action that precedes it: She had been possessing people *when she lived on the bayou*.

Comment: @anouk: I recall commenting under your question *while casting a "duplicate" closevote*, but it wasn't me who deleted the comment. At least one user regularly complains about me "posting answers as comments". And at least one mod here strongly agrees with that position, so presumably that's why my comment was deleted :(  I'm afraid that even if I could remember exactly what I wrote before, there's probably no point in me repeating it. (That mod would probably just delete it again, and send me another email threatening banishment from the site if I don't mend my ways! :)

Comment: ...sorry I can't be more helpful. If you're *really* stuck, ping me with another comment here and I'll try to respond by posting an "Answer" against the earlier question that I cited in my closevote.

Comment: The linked question contains, and the only answer to it concentrates on the effect of the word "all", so in my view it is not a duplicate, because possible answers to this question are unlikely to be given to the linked Q.

Answer (score 2):

*She has been possessing* people implies that she is still acquiring new people to possess. *She has possessed people* means that she has done that in the past, but does not necessarily mean she is still doing that. She may still be, but it is a bit more ambiguous than *she has been*.